# XPages OpenNTF ViewGrid v1.5 onRowClick

Tags: javascript, xpages

The [OpenNTF ViewGrid](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20ViewGrid) has a property **onRowClick**. The property description is "name of javascript function to call on document click". I created a csjs library with a simple test function e.g.

```
function test(){
    alert("Hello world");
}
```

and then entered `test()` into the `onRowClick` property. When I open the Xpage the alert is shown when the Xpage starts loading. It does not show when a document row is clicked. What am I doing wrong here? I thought from the name and description of the property that it would run a function when you clicked on a document row. Any tips on what might be wrong would be really appreciated.....

Comment: If I were you, I would reach out to Ferry Kranenburg who authored this and invited people to reach out to him with questions.  He is frequently on SO, so perhaps shoot him a email to check out your question.

Comment: Dale, I just saw that you had already asked Ferry in the discussion section. BTW. I am not sure why your question was downvoted, it is clear what you are asking, and what you tried.

Comment: Dale, I have not looked into the source code but try adding "test" instead of "test()" for the onRowClick property.

Comment: I think Per answered this correctly ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much Per. That worked great! Unfortunately I cannot vote on or accept your answer because, on my question, the controls for that do not appear for me (logged in on any browser). The stackoverflow help says that the controls should be there.Possibly the reason is that I just signed up on stackoverflow last night and have only 11 points or maybe because the question was edited?